# Atmel UC3A0512 microcontroller documentation

Tags: atmel, atmel-studio, avr32

I started using this microcontroller but I am dealing with the lack of documentation. First of all this is the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT32UC3A0512AU.aspx?tab=documents). It describes registers and their usage but not a workflow. Which one to set first, which second etc. [The ASF Get Started](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/get_started.html) quick guides are very limited to high level staff, like USB protocol etc. At last, there are existing examples which demonstrate but it is a mess with out a documentation.

Comment: Have you never worked with microcontrollers before? This is a pretty typical datasheet.

Comment: I have experience with PIC microcontrollers and things were much simpler than that. There is no documentation on how to set things. Only existing examples.

Comment: PIC datasheets only call out specific orders to do things when it matters, eg. EEPROM writes. How is this one any different?

Comment: @MattYoung Well can you find any quick guides on how to use this microcontroller? How to properly set ADC? Because I can't.

Comment: That link isn't to a datasheet, some kind of product page instead.  Link to the actual datasheet.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32058.pdf

Comment: In _that EXACT datasheet_ there is a whole bleeding section on the ADC that has a functional description, conversion timing, register description with full explanation of what each bit does and means. If that's not good enough for you in terms of a datasheet you're shit out of luck in the industry, because I have only seen _less documentation than that_ in 20 years of work with (semi-)professional devices.

Answer (score 6):

Good datasheets tell you what the part does, not how to use it for whatever your particular purpose is.  It turns out your link is not to a datasheet, some product page apparently, so I can't comment on this particular datasheet directly.

If datasheets provided the hand-holding you are asking for, they would get irritating very fast to everyone that didn't care to use the part in whatever particular way the paint-by-numbers instruction say.  Not only would that dilute the real information that everyone else is there to get, but any particular recipe will be wrong in a number of circumstances.

The correct procedure is to read the datasheet to understand how the part works.  Then you can synthesize your own method of harnessing those capabilities to achieve what you want.  Information beyond that really doesn't belong in a datasheet.

This is what app notes are for.  They are examples of how to use parts in particular ways.  Go look for app notes related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: The page is the devices documents page. The first pdf is the datasheet.

Comment: @George: Exactly.  The link is to some product page, not a datasheet.  No, I'm not going to go digging around to discover the "first pdf" is what I'm actually looking for.  Don't be so lazy.

Comment: Here you are http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32058.pdf